# Manage Configuration file access setting from one place

Tags: asp.net, file-permissions

We have single lower environment server where we publish all our applications for Developer testing, pre-business testing etc. Problem we are facing here is all the developers changing settings in the config file for their convenience.

For example, development application should point development SQL db, but they are changing it to QA. and in some cases instead of publishing the application to staging they are changing QA connection strings to staging because publishing to staging requires extra effort (Merging the code to Main branch etc). No matter how many times we send email to development group they keep doing the same thing.

Is there a way to control web.config/app.config edit permissions and limit it to one person based on the application?

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server Connection String is the problem, you can use **cliconfg.exe** to set a specific ALIAS, in this case you must configure the alias on each server in your environment (development, test and production), with this, the connection string will always be "Data Source = SRVDBAPP" on the web. config / app.config.
Internally each client SQL Server will redirect to the corresponding database.